# Date Format effecting non date related search query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I feel like the answer to this is probably gonna be a pretty duh thing, but i  played endlessly with trying to get the universal date picker to show the proper date in react and  came up with INTL.datetime('fr-ca' etc etc) and then replace the slashes with -. Great it works on the searches involving dates. I try to do the get for no date ranges and it spits back an error and wont display the return

Here is error

```
react-dom.development.js:1383 The specified value "Tue Dec 01 2020 09:52:36 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".
```

Here is my code for the entire component. Should i useeffect for getDups() and just set the time value to nothing?

```
import React, { useState,useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import ListItem from "./ListItem";
import KeyModal from "./KeyModal";
import LeadContext from "../context/lead/leadContext";

const ListViewer = () => {
  const leadContext = useContext(LeadContext);

  const { leads, clearLeads, getLexs, keys, postLeads, getDups,sendTodays,getReleases } = leadContext;

  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date(Date.now()))
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(new Date(Date.now()))

  const onChange = e =>{
     setStartDate(e.target.value)
  } 

  const onChange2 = e =>{
         setEndDate(e.target.value) 
  }   


  console.log(leads)
  const dates = {startDate, endDate}    
  return (
    <div className='grid-2'>
      <div>
    <button className="p-2 btn btn-sm btn-danger" onClick={()=>getDups()}> Get All Dups </button>  
       <button className="p-2 btn btn-sm btn-success" onClick={()=>sendTodays()}>Send Todays Scrapes</button>
    <button className="p-2 btn btn-sm btn-primary" onClick={()=>getReleases(dates)}>Get Range Releases</button>    
      <button className="btn btn-sm btn-dark" onClick={()=>getLexs(dates)}>Get Range Lexis Info</button>

     </div>
      <div>
        <form>
      <div className='grid-2'>
           
      <div>
        <label>Enter a Date Range </label>
            <input
              type='date'
              name='startDate'
              value={
                startDate &&
                Intl.DateTimeFormat("fr-CA", {
                  year: "numeric",
                  month: "numeric",
                  day: "numeric",
                }).format(new Date(startDate).replace(/-/, '/').replace(/-/,'/'))
              }
              id='startDate'
              onChange={onChange}
            /> 
           </div>
      <div>
         <input
              type='date'
              name='endDate'
              value={
                startDate &&
                Intl.DateTimeFormat("fr-CA", {
                  year: "numeric",
                  month: "numeric",
                  day: "numeric",
                }).format(new Date(endDate).replace(/-/, '/').replace(/-/,'/'))
              }
              id='endDate'
              onChange={onChange2}
            />
      </div>
      </div>
    </form>  
  ).format(new Date(e.target.value.replace(/-/, '/').replace(/-/,
      

     </div>
    {keys.length > 0 ? <KeyModal keys={keys}/> :''}   
      <br/>
      <br/>
            
      {leads.length > 0 ? 
      
      <div className='grid-2'>
        <div> <button onClick={()=>clearLeads()} className='btn btn-dark btn-block'>Clear Leads</button></div>
        <div> <button onClick={()=>postLeads(leads)}className='btn btn-success btn-block'>Post Leads</button></div>

      
      </div>:''}
      <div className = 'grid-2'>

       <div>      {leads.length > 0 ?         leads.filter(function(item) {
           return item["dob"] === undefined;
        
          }).map((lead) => <ListItem key={lead.dupId} lead={lead} />)
        : ""}</div>
       <div>      
         {leads.length > 0 ?
         
         leads.filter(function(item) {
           return item["dob"] !== undefined;
        
          }).map((lead) => <ListItem key={lead.dupId} lead={lead} />)
        
        : ""}</div> 


        </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ListViewer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The MDN docs on <input type="date">](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Value) state that:

> the parsed value is always formatted yyyy-mm-dd

So you shouldn't pass a `Date` object in your inputs' `value` attribute, since a `Date`'s default string representation is something like:

*Tue Dec 01 2020 09:52:36 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)*

when `value` should be:

*2020-12-01*

What appears in the `<input type="date">` text box is up to the browser locale, you cannot change the way the date appears in a native date picker.

A few other pointers as well:

- `new Date(Date.now())` is redundant, you may use `new Date()` without any arguments to get a `Date` object pointing to the present instead.
- You cannot use `replace()` functions on `Date` objects - not before turning them into Strings, you'll get an Error otherwise. You probably meant to do:

  ```js
  Intl.DateTimeFormat("fr-CA", {
                  year: "numeric",
                  month: "numeric",
                  day: "numeric",
                }).format(new Date(endDate)).replaceAll('-', '/')
  ```
- Speaking of `replace()`, you don't have to chain `replace()` twice to substitute all dashes (-) for slashes (/). You can use a `replaceAll()` like above, or type `replace(/-/g, '/')` (notice the "g" after the regular expression object).

Not that the above pointers solve your problem. You still have to convert your `Date` in a "yyyy-MM-dd" string.

Comment: replaceAll must be newish

Comment: You are correct. `replaceAll()` is indeed very recent.

Comment: If you pass the date as a string to the component, you don't have to convert it into the correct format. Alternatively you could use [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) if a Date object is passed. `date.toISOString().split("T", 1)[0]` or `date.toISOString().slice(0, 10)`.